# Convert column values to column of list based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

Dataset as:

```
   id  col2  col3
0   1     1   123
1   1     1   234
2   1     0   345
3   2     1   456
4   2     0  1243
5   2     0   346
6   3     0   888
7   3     0   999
8   3     0   777
```

I would like to aggregate data by `id`, and append the values of `col3` into a list only if its corresponding value at `col2` is 1. Additionally, for people (of different `id`) who only have 0 in `col2`, I like the aggregated value to be 0 for `col2` and empty list for `col3`.

Here is the current code:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], 'col2':[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'col3':[123, 234, 345, 456, 1243, 346, 888, 999, 777]})

df_test_agg = pd.pivot_table(df_test, index=['id'], values=['col2', 'col3'], aggfunc={'col2':np.max, 'col3':(lambda x:list(x))})

print (df_test_agg)

    col2              col3
id                        
1      1   [123, 234, 345]
2      1  [456, 1243, 346]
3      0   [888, 999, 777]
```

The desired output should be (ideally in one-step in Pandas):

```
    col2              col3
id                        
1      1            [123, 234]
2      1            [456]
3      0            []
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Edit - Trying out ColdSpeed's solution

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], 'col2':[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'col3':[123, 234, 345, 456, 1243, 346, 888, 999, 777]})

print (df_test)

df_test_agg = (df_test.where(df_test.col2 > 0)
    .assign(id=df_test.id)
    .groupby('id')
    .agg({'col2': 'max', 'col3': lambda x: x.dropna().tolist()}))

print (df_test_agg)

   id  col2  col3
0   1     1   123
1   1     1   234
2   1     0   345
3   2     1   456
4   2     0  1243
5   2     0   346
6   3     0   888
7   3     0   999
8   3     0   777
    col2            col3
id                      
1    1.0  [123.0, 234.0]
2    1.0         [456.0]
3    NaN              []
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Edited original post to present more scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter beforehand, then use `groupby`:

```
df_test.query('col2 > 0').groupby('id').agg({'col2': 'max', 'col3': list})

    col2        col3
id                  
1      1  [123, 234]
2      1       [456]
```

The caveat here is that if a group has only zeros, that group will be missing in the result. So, to fix that, you can mask with `where`:

```
(df_test.where(df_test.col2 > 0)
        .assign(id=df_test.id)
        .groupby('id')
        .agg({'col2': 'max', 'col3'lambda x: x.dropna().tolist()}))

    col2            col3
id                      
1    1.0  [123.0, 234.0]
2    1.0         [456.0]
```

---

To handle 0 groups in "col2", we can use

```
(df.assign(col3=df.col3.where(df.col2.astype(bool)))
   .groupby('id')
   .agg({'col2':'max', 'col3': lambda x: x.dropna().astype(int).tolist()}))

    col2        col3
id                  
1      1  [123, 234]
2      1       [456]
3      0          []
```

Comment: I do want to retain the col2=0 group. That's why I prefer a one step solution than filtering out some subgroup first.

Comment: @KubiK888 There's no one step solution, because `agg` in this state only has access to a single series, not multiple columns. Is there anything wrong with the second suggestion?

Comment: Will test your second solution while on a computer. Thanks.

Comment: Please see edit, your second solution is certainly better than the first, but it still gives `NaN` instead of the desired 0 for `col2` for `id`=3. Is that what you mean by not possible to have a One-step solution? I can replace `NaN` with 0 as the next step, but just want to make sure Pandas can't handle that in one step.

Comment: @KubiK888 There might be a way. Can you modify your sample data in the question to include the case that is not working properly with this code? I'll see if I can fix it. (edit your question)

Comment: @KubiK888 Just made the fixes, let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks @coldspeed, it works, would you mind briefly explaining what's happening within the assign function?

Comment: @KubiK888 It is a way of assigning a new column (or reassigning an existing column) without modifying the original DataFrame. The expression `df.col3.where(df.col2.astype(bool))` will convert all col3 values to NaN where col2 is 0.

Comment: Just one last question, the 'col3'  created within `assign` is a new column that was later applied with the lambda function, correct?

Comment: @KubiK888 Yes. The original `df` is not modified. `assign` creates a copy of the DataFrame and assigns a new column to that copy before returning it. If you would prefer in-place assignment, that's fine too, but that's two steps ;-)